# Conditional variance $\hat{\beta}_1|x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, regression-coefficients, coefficient-of-variation, conditional-variance

Why do we need to estimate the variance of $\hat{\beta}_1|x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$ when we want to test a hypothesis about $\beta_1$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485676/meaning-of-standard-error-of-the-coefficients-in-a-regression-model/485680#485680 and the comments provided there